# Updating qiskit.chemistry.core.Hamiltonian to qiskit-nature Framework

Tags: qiskit, chemistry

I recently saw a piece of code that computes molecular bond energy with respect to bond length. I am trying to update the code to the newer qiskit framework (I'm running qiskit 0.45.1 and `qiskit-nature` instead of the depricated `qiskit.chemistry`). The complete original code is available as a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-A6G0WVI9w&t=1291s), but I have extracted the relevant parts below.

In order to generate a qubit operator associated with the Hamiltonian in the process of finding the eigen energy, the older version of qiskit uses the class `qiskit.chemistry.core.Hamiltonian`, which does not exist anymore in `qiskit_nature`.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative way to generate the `qubitOp` such that I can use `NumPyMinimumEigensolver().run()` to find the exact bond energy? In other words, how can I make the following piece of code run correctly using `qiskit-nature`?

```
driver = PySCFDriver(atom=moleculeRepr.format(dist/2), basis="sto3g")
molecule = driver.run()
operator = Hamiltonian(qubit_mapping=QubitMappingtype.PARITY, two_qubit_reduction=True, freeze_core=True,orbital_reduction=[-3, -2])
qubitOp, aux_ops = operator.run(molecule)

#classical result
exactResult = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubitOp, aux_operators=aux_ops).run()
exactResult = operator.process_algorithm_result(exactResult)
```

Any help or insights into this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Things have changed a lot from the fotmer chemistry code to Nature. I would suggest looking at the Nature tutorials https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/tutorials/index.html which include showing the NumPyMinimumEigensolver in use. Also look at the getting started sample https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/getting_started.html#ready-to-get-going which you can replace VQE there by that solver.